# How to upload a ContentVersion with lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, contentversion, aura-attribute

I'm trying to use simple apex class and simple controller like a test. But can't upload ContentVersion. What is wrong here?

```
handleFileSelected: function(component, event, helper) {
    let files = event.getParam("files");
    let file = files[0];

    let reader = new FileReader();                
    reader.onload = function (e) {

        let targRes =  e.target.result;
        let action = component.get("c.save");
        action.setParams({
            firstPublishLocationId : 'a010E000004PRC3QAO',  //real Id
            versionData : targRes
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);           
},
```

apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static void save(String firstPublishLocationId Blob versionData){ 
        ContentVersion currentContentVersion = new ContentVersion(
            Title = 'test',
            PathOnClient = 'test',
            VersionData = versionData,
            FirstPublishLocationId = firstPublishLocationId
        ); 
        insert currentContentVersion;
    }
```

Comment: Your Lightning parameters do not match your Apex method's parameters. Does this reflect real code, or is this poorly anonymized? What specific error are you receiving?

Comment: It's a test code, like I say. No errors. I just don't get a cv like related with my record. And don't know, how to make it right with lightning

Comment: Right now, your Lightning controller is not populating `firstPublishLocationId`, and your Apex controller has a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry. I changed it. But still the same.

Answer (score 2):

This FileUpload Component might work for you:

```
 <c:FileUpload parentId="" label="" />
```

Where `parentId` is the record the file will be attached to.

**Component**

```
<aura:component controller="FileUploadController">
    <aura:attribute name="parentId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="label" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="uploading" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:handler event="aura:waiting" action="{!c.waiting}" />
    <aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting" action="{!c.doneWaiting}" />
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.uploading}">
        <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading" size="large" />
    </aura:if>
    <div>
        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <span class="slds-form-element__label" id="file-selector-primary-label">{! v.label }</span>
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <div class="slds-file-selector slds-file-selector_files">
                    <div class="slds-file-selector__dropzone">

                        <input aura:id="file" class="slds-file-selector__input slds-assistive-text" type="file" id="file-upload-input-01"
                            aria-labelledby="file-selector-primary-label file-selector-secondary-label" />
                        <label class="slds-file-selector__body" for="file-upload-input-01" id="file-selector-secondary-label">
                            <span class="slds-file-selector__button slds-button slds-button_neutral">
                                <lightning:icon iconName="utility:upload" size="xx-small" alternativeText="upload" />Upload
                                Files</span>
                            <span class="slds-file-selector__text slds-medium-show">or Drop Files</span>
                            <span>
                                <ui:button label="Upload" press="{!c.save}" />
                            </span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**JavaScript Controller**

```
({
    save: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.save(component);
    },
    waiting: function (component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.uploading", true);
    },
    doneWaiting: function (component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.uploading", false);
    }
})
```

**JavaScript Helper**

```
({
    MAX_FILE_SIZE: 4500000, /* 6 000 000 * 3/4 to account for base64 */
    CHUNK_SIZE: 950000, /* Use a multiple of 4 */

    save: function (component) {
        var fileInput = component.find("file").getElement();
        var file = fileInput.files[0];

        if (file.size > this.MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
            alert('File size cannot exceed ' + this.MAX_FILE_SIZE + ' bytes.\n' +
                'Selected file size: ' + file.size);
            return;
        }

        var fr = new FileReader();

        var self = this;
        fr.onload = function () {
            var fileContents = fr.result;
            var base64Mark = 'base64,';
            var dataStart = fileContents.indexOf(base64Mark) + base64Mark.length;

            fileContents = fileContents.substring(dataStart);

            self.upload(component, file, fileContents);
        };

        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    },
    upload: function (component, file, fileContents) {
        var fromPos = 0;
        var toPos = Math.min(fileContents.length, fromPos + this.CHUNK_SIZE);

        // start with the initial chunk
        this.uploadChunk(component, file, fileContents, fromPos, toPos, '');
    },
    uploadChunk: function (component, file, fileContents, fromPos, toPos, attachId) {
        console.log('uploadChunk');
        var action = component.get("c.saveTheChunk");
        var chunk = fileContents.substring(fromPos, toPos);

        action.setParams({
            parentId: component.get("v.parentId"),
            fileName: file.name,
            base64Data: encodeURIComponent(chunk),
            contentType: file.type,
            fileId: attachId
        });

        var self = this;
        action.setCallback(this, function (a) {

            console.log('uploadChunk: Callback');
            attachId = a.getReturnValue();

            fromPos = toPos;
            toPos = Math.min(fileContents.length, fromPos + self.CHUNK_SIZE);

            if (fromPos < toPos) {
                self.uploadChunk(component, file, fileContents, fromPos, toPos, attachId);
            } else {
                console.log('uploadChunk: done');
                self.showToast('Upload Complete', 'You file has successfully uploaded, please upload another now.', 'success', null);
            }
        });

        $A.getCallback(function () {
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        })();
    },
    showToast: function (title, message, type, icon) {
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            duration: '2000',
            key: icon,
            type: type,
            mode: 'dismissible'
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
    },
})
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public without sharing class FileUploadController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Id saveTheFile(Id parentId, String fileName, String base64Data, String contentType) { 
        base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');
        ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
            versionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data),
            title = fileName,
            pathOnClient =  '/' + fileName,
            FirstPublishLocationId = parentId);
        insert contentVersion; 
        return contentVersion.Id;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Id saveTheChunk(Id parentId, String fileName, String base64Data, String contentType, String fileId) { 
        if (fileId == '') {
            fileId = saveTheFile(parentId, fileName, base64Data, contentType);
        } else {
            appendToFile(fileId, base64Data);
        }
        return Id.valueOf(fileId);
    }

    private static void appendToFile(Id fileId, String base64Data) {
        base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');
        ContentVersion contentVersion = [
            SELECT Id, versionData
            FROM ContentVersion
            WHERE Id = :fileId
        ];
        String existingBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(contentVersion.versionData);
        contentVersion.versionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(existingBody + base64Data); 
        update contentVersion;   
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.THIS .notUploading {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.THIS .uploading {
    visibility: visible;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.THIS .small-spinner {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

.THIS .file {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: block;
}
```

- [Gist: Salesforce Lightning FileUpload Component](https://gist.github.com/SalesforceBobLightning/7e244fe097390000c45a7db2a0957aa4)

Comment: Can you add relevant code bits? Link only answers generally gets downvoted and marked as low quality

Comment: @PranayJaiswal added

Comment: Thanks Robs. +1